# How can I remove all characters in each line after the first space in a text file?

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell, text-manipulation

I have a large log file from which I need to extract file names.

The file looks like this:

```
/path/to/loremIpsumDolor.sit /more/text/here/notAlways/theSame/here
/path/to/anotherFile.ext /more/text/here/differentText/here
.... about 10 million times
```

I need to extract the file names like this:

```
loremIpsumDolor.sit
anotherFile.ext
```

I figure my first strategy is to find/replace all `/path/to/` with ''.  But I'm stuck how to remove all characters after the space.

Can you help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed 's/ .*//' file
```

It doesn't take any more.  The transformed output appears on standard output, of course.

Comment: umm... regex for stripping after the first space? Wouldn't expect that from you ;-)

Comment: Brute force `sed` action; I like it. It is a shame that Windows does not provide such powerful text manipulation tools like sed, grep, awk, etc. by default. These are the bread-n-butter tools for a sys admin (IMHO).

Comment: I dislike 'cut' because the standard ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html)) versions of it don't handle one-or-more separators between fields; GNU `cut` has the necessary `-i` option, but I can't always rely on having GNU `cut` available. Granted, not an issue with this particular task, but if you don't use a tool because it doesn't always work, you don't use it.  I find `sed` easier to use, but there are multiple tools for the job (`awk`, `perl`, `python` could all be used very easily, but they're more complex than necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I find `sed` more complex *for this particular task*. That's why I didn't expect that from you. (and no tool *always work*). That said, expected or not, I do not find anything severely wrong with this solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Pass it to `cut`:

```
cut '-d ' -f1 yourfile
```

Comment: You don't need the input redirection, though it does no harm here while there's only a single file to process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, true. Even thought of it after submitting. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could also use `awk` to grab the filename from each line as:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' input_file.log
```

That, of course, assumes that there are no spaces in any of the filenames. `awk` defaults to looking for whitespace as the field delimiters, so the above snippet would take the first "field" from your log file (your filename) for each line, and output it.

Comment: Ah, but there are actually spaces before in my real log file.  But I like this direction.  In reality it's more like `textHere thenSpaces /path/to/file.ext /more/text/here`.  I didn't mention it because I figured I'd have to sed find/replace the first part anyway (since it's always the same).

Comment: @Ryan: no sweat; you would just use `print $2` instead, since it would then be the second field. `awk` is a handy tool for things just such as this, and it is worth getting reasonably good at using it.

Answer (score 0):

a bash-only solution:

```
while read path otherstuff; do
    echo ${path##*/}
done < filename
```